# Is there anyway to read .dat file from movielens to R studio

Tags: r, notepad++, rstudio

I am trying to use Import Dataset in R Studio to read ratings.dat from movielens.
Basically it has this format:

```
 1::1::5::978824268  
 1::1022::5::978300055
 1::1028::5::978301777 
 1::1029::5::978302205 
 1::1035::5::978301753
```

So I need to replace :: by : or ' or white spaces, etc. I use notepad++, it helps to load the file quite fast (compare to note) and can view very big file easily. However, when I do replacement, it shows some strange characters:

```
"LF"
```

as I do some research here, it said that it is \n (line feed or line break). But I do not know why when it load the file, it do not show these, only when I do replacement then they appear. And when I load into R Studio, it still detect as "LF", not line break and cause error in data reading.

What is the solution for that ? Thank you !
PS: I know there is python code for converting this but I don't want to use it, is there any other ways ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively (use the d/l code from jlhoward but he also updated his code to not use built-in functions and switch to data.table while i wrote this, but mine's still faster/more efficient :-)

```
library(data.table)

# i try not to use variable names that stomp on function names in base
URL <- "http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m.zip"

# this will be "ml-10m.zip"
fil <- basename(URL) 

# this will download to getwd() since you prbly want easy access to 
# the files after the machinations. the nice thing about this is
# that it won't re-download the file and waste bandwidth
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

# this will create the "ml-10M100K" dir in getwd(). if using
# R 3.2+ you can do a dir.exists() test to avoid re-doing the unzip
# (which is useful for large archives or archives compressed with a 
# more CPU-intensive algorithm)   
unzip(fil)

# fast read and slicing of the input
# fread will only spit on a single delimiter so the initial fread
# will create a few blank columns. the [] expression filters those
# out. the "with=FALSE" is part of the data.table inanity
mov <- fread("ml-10M100K/ratings.dat", sep=":")[, c(1,3,5,7), with=FALSE]

# saner column names, set efficiently via data.table::setnames
setnames(mov, c("user_id", "movie_id", "tag", "timestamp"))

mov
##           user_id movie_id tag timestamp
##        1:       1      122   5 838985046
##        2:       1      185   5 838983525
##        3:       1      231   5 838983392
##        4:       1      292   5 838983421
##        5:       1      316   5 838983392
##       ---                               
## 10000050:   71567     2107   1 912580553
## 10000051:   71567     2126   2 912649143
## 10000052:   71567     2294   5 912577968
## 10000053:   71567     2338   2 912578016
## 10000054:   71567     2384   2 912578173
```

It's quite a bit faster than built-in functions.

Comment: fread is not available for my current R Studio version (  package ‘fread’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
What is the alternative way ?

Comment: what is the meaning of adding this: [, c(1,3,5,7), with=FALSE] ?

Comment: I see, so is it gsub("::", "\t", ratings) is a more general approach? can use it in this case ?

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
url <- "http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m.zip"

## this part is agonizingly slow
tf <- tempfile()
download.file(url,tf, mode="wb")                          # download archived movielens data
files    <- unzip(tf, exdir=tempdir())                    # unzips and returns a vector of file names
ratings <- readLines(files[grepl("ratings.dat$",files)])  # read rating.dat file
ratings <- gsub("::", "\t", ratings)

# this part is much faster
library(data.table)
ratings <- fread(paste(ratings, collapse="\n"), sep="\t")
# Read 10000054 rows and 4 (of 4) columns from 0.219 GB file in 00:00:07
head(ratings)
#    V1  V2 V3        V4
# 1:  1 122  5 838985046
# 2:  1 185  5 838983525
# 3:  1 231  5 838983392
# 4:  1 292  5 838983421
# 5:  1 316  5 838983392
# 6:  1 329  5 838983392
```

Comment: Just realized that you want the ratings and not the movies. This is a much bigger table, so better to use `fread(...)` in `data.table` package.

Comment: Thank you for very nice code. I have up-voted your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement to @hrbrmstr's answer:

```
mov <- fread("ml-10M100K/ratings.dat", sep=":", select=c(1,3,5,7))
```